# Managing .NET internal project references

Tags: .net, reference, nuget

First of all, i am not that into .NET world (still learning). I am trying to build my project with external and internal references.

External references are OK. I manage them with Nuget.

But what about internal references?

My project structure is something like that:

```
My Solution (.sln)
  -> Project A (.csproj)
  -> Project B (.csproj)
  -> Project C (.csproj)
```

I mean, if i want to refere Project A in Project B, what do i have to do?

Is there any way to manage internal reference dll's with current version of the whole project in csproj? (like project.version variable in Maven)

Comment: You meant: `internal reference` is something like `internal class BaseClass {}`, right?

Comment: Yes, i guess so. But my main interest is csproj file dll reference and build operations in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution explorer, Right-Click on Project B and follow Add->Reference menu. 
In Reference Manager window, under the Projects menu Click the Project A and hit Ok

Comment: Ok, i have added the reference. But when it is placed on, where is the exact configuration that tells the msbuild "here is my reference to another internal project". In csproj?

Comment: Yes. When you add a project reference to the project. Visual Studio automatically generates this information in csproj. If you want to see csproj file through the Visual Studio, you need the unload project. To unload a project, in solution explorer right click on the project and hit the unload project and then right click again and click the "Edit xyz.csproj

Comment: Finally, when you run, build or rebuild project, visual studio builds relevant projects and generates all files and copy them to Bin folder.